# Dart: filter lists with maps

Tags: flutter, dart

LIST 1: I have a list with user ids: (selected users)

```
['1234', '3455', '2330', '1111']
```

LIST 2: I have a second list with the full profile of the users (map): (all users)

```
[{"id": '1234', "name": "username"}, {"id": '3455' .... ]
```

LIST 3: I would like to have a third list that contains all selected users: returning all users of LIST 2 that have an id of LIST 1.

I tried this...

```
 list1.forEach((element) =>
         list3.add(list2.where((data) => data['id'] == element)));
```

But that doesn't work...

```
error: The argument type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `list3 = list2.where((map)=>list1.contains(map["id"])).toList()` for create list3

And the reason of issue is your list3 needs a map, but your `list2.where(..)` code is returns `List[map, map, map]`.

Comment: You can also use a list literal computation like `list3 = [for (var map in list2) if (list1.contains(map["id"])) map];`.

Answer (score 4):

There are few possible ways to do this. One simple way is to go through your second list and check if the user id is in the first list using `List` `contains()`.

Ex:

Using `map()`:

```
  List ids = ['1234', '3455', '2330', '1111'];
  List users = [{"id": '1234', "name": "username"}, {"id": '3455', "name": "username"}];
  List selectedUsers = users.map((user) {
    if(ids.contains(user["id"])) return user;
    return null;
  }).toList();
```

another way to use `forEach()`:

```
  List selectedUsers = [];
  users.forEach((u) {
    if(ids.contains(u["id"])) selectedUsers.add(u);
  });
  print(selectedUsers);
```

We don't need much code for this(`where()` is handy):

```
List selectedUsers = users.where((u) => ids.contains(u["id"])).toList();
```

Edit this in [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/fb0518a5fa9f32bff68549c77f086b09).

And other possible methods to make it even easy Dart provides you few methods like `where()` and if you want to replace your second list `retainsWhere() and removeWhere()`. For more read [Dart List](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: Thanks! works, but the list selectedUsers has a few null elements. The answer of Ibrahim Karahan hasn't. Flutter also gives a message : the function has a return type..., but doesn't end with a return statement...